# Not able to retrive data from DateTime in mysql

Tags: java

I want to retrive datetime column value to javacode.

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Time {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws ClassNotFoundException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        DAO1.getDBObject();
    }

}
//STEP 1. Import required packages


 class DAO1 {
 // JDBC driver name and database URL
 static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
 static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/coder";

 //  Database credentials
 static final String USER = "root";
 static final String PASS = "root";
 static  ArrayList<member> al = new ArrayList<member>();

 public static ArrayList<member> getDBObject() throws ClassNotFoundException {
 Connection conn = null;
 Statement stmt = null;
 try{
    //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
       al.clear();
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    //STEP 3: Open a connection
    System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);

    //STEP 4: Execute a query
    System.out.println("Creating statement...");
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    String sql;
    sql = "SELECT id, name, payType FROM gym";
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

    //STEP 5: Extract data from result set
    while(rs.next()){

       ***//System.out.println(rs.getTimestamp("lastPaid"));
       System.out.println(rs.getDate(3));***

    }
    //STEP 6: Clean-up environment

    }catch(SQLException se){
       se.printStackTrace();
    }//end finally try//end try

 return al;
}//end main
}//end FirstExample
```

am getting exception like this

> Creating statement... java.sql.SQLException: Bad format for DATE '6'
>   in column 3.  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1056)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:957)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetRow.getDateFast(ResultSetRow.java:254)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ByteArrayRow.getDateFast(ByteArrayRow.java:235)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getDate(ResultSetImpl.java:2108)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getDate(ResultSetImpl.java:2060)     at
>   DAO1.getDBObject(Time.java:53)    at Time.main(Time.java:11)

and my mysql database looks like

[image]

**Im trying all methods getDate,getTimeStamp with indexing and string versions.
all were giving exceptions only.
Please help me**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't querying the date in your sql. Try:

```
sql = "SELECT id, name, payType, lastPaid FROM gym";
```

or

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM gym";
```

Comment: You will also need to get the right column in your rs.get statement

Comment: wow!!! thanks a lot...am trying this from 2 hrs..oh i missed that column in qurey...

Comment: Happens to us all! Taking a break from the code for a bit usually helps!